# Import Text file in R

Tags: r, import, text-files

I have a data in a text file. I have a problem importing it to R. The example of the text file looks like this :

> holes:1     must:1     top_secret:1     he:1     center:1     other_civilans:1 the_pacific:1     the_navy:1     a_lot:1     surface_must:1     this_book:1 man_named:1     _feet:2

There are many lines of data like the above. 
It would be great if anyone could help me in solving this!!

Thanks in advance!!

I want the file to be read in two columns like

```
holes        1  
must         1
top_secret   1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- data.frame('name' = scan('input_file.txt', what = 'list', sep =' '))
x$name <- as.character(x$name)
x$value <- substr(x$name, start = nchar(x$name), stop = nchar(x$name))
x$name <- substr(x$name, start = 1, stop = nchar(x$name) - 2)
print(x)
             name value
1           holes     1
2            must     1
3      top_secret     1
4              he     1
5          center     1
6  other_civilans     1
7     the_pacific     1
8        the_navy     1
9           a_lot     1
10   surface_must     1
11      this_book     1
12      man_named     1
13     <num>_feet     2
```

Comment: Some observations are like this : 

149
days_couldnt:1 me_tell:1 style:1 style_and:1 real:1 to_solve:1 reviews:1    Help me to overcome this problem

Comment: Any idea how to overcome the above problem?

Comment: @KasiPerumal Be more specific. What exactly is your problem? This answer works fine for me, you should accept it.